# Writing the log to a .csv file with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Writing my first google script and I hit a wall on what I expected to be a simple task.

At the end of my script I want to dump everything in the log into a .csv file that I'll store in the root directory of Drive.

I've found a ton of documentation on how to send the log via email, but nothing on how to dump it to a .csv or spreadsheet.

Any tips?

Comment: You can store a text file with one line, `DriveApp.createFile('my log', 'my log contents');` Is the problem in conversion to csv? If so, from what format?

Comment: Seems as if Logger.getLog() returns a string rather than an array. Not entirely sure how it will be separated (can't check atm), probably just comma, but no new lines, so the entire contents would probably end up on one row. So firstly check the output of this method, and we can proceed from there to save as CSV. Share what you discover.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your script, you should retrieve the log with

```
var data = Logger.getLog();
```

Then write the data to a new CSV file, which is a defined MimeType with Google Drive. ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename-content-mimetype))

```
DriveApp.createFile('New CSV File', data, MimeType.CSV);
```